# Git Diff To Find Which Lines Have Been Added and Which Deleted

Tags: bash, git, git-diff

I have a `git diff` command that tells me how many lines have been deleted and added for each file between my current branch and master.  Here it is:

```
git diff master --merge-base --numstat
```

It gives output similar to this:

```
3       2       a.yml
1       1       b.yml
0       1       c.yml
```

What I would like in addition to this is the line numbers of the files of the deleted lines and added lines for each file.  How can I do this?

Comment: So you want most of the diff information except for the actual added/removed content? This feels like a weird [XY roblem](https://xyproblem.info). What's the underlying problem you're trying to solve? Also I think it's important to point out that "lines added" and "lines removed" are purely down to which diff algorithm is used, they are not "real" or "absolute" in any meaningful sense in git.

Comment: What OS are you using ? Also why not use a GUI tool for this?

Comment: @MikeQ MacOS, but this will be deployed to a Ubuntu Linux environment.  This has to be done in a script so I need something programmatic rather than graphical.

Comment: @JoachimSauer What I'm trying to do is find out which lines are deleted and which are added so that I can perform the set difference between them in order to find out only the NEW lines added or OLD lines deleted, rather than lines that are updated, because I want to find out if there are any added lines.

Comment: But that's the thing: from the information stored in git (basically the old state and the new state) you can't reliably tell which changes were "real" additions/removals and which ones were just "modifications". And even if you're okay with that unreliability, different diff algorithms will give you different answers to this question.

Comment: @JoachimSauer You make a good point.  To avoid the XY problem let me tell you what it is I'm trying to do.  I have some files with variables in one folder and some template files in another. I want to create a github action that checks PRs where files in these folders have been changed.  I want to ensure that if something is added or deleted in the templates folder then it is also added or deleted in the variables folder and vice versa.  So that we never have a mismatch.

Comment: To simplify - Read the master file, get all of the variables etc you want to account for, then read the PR file and do the same. Report on what was removed and what was added by comparing the results. Too simple?

Comment: I'd suggest the same approach as @MikeQ. I wouldn't risk going into the "what's added, what's removed" debate and just check for parity in what exists, that seems way more reliable and stable to me.